# Magical Record, how to use saveWithBlock and still access imported data afterwards

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

the idea is to import server JSON response into core data without blocking UI on main thread, I still need the imported entities afterwards, after a whole morning testing/googling, I failed to find the right way to do this.

```
__block NSMutableArray *cars;
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    for (NSDictionary *carObject in carObjects) {
        Notification *car = [Notification MR_importFromObject:carObject inContext:localContext];
        [cars addObject:car];
    }
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        for (Car *car in cars) {
            // data may have invalid data or be nil
            // [Car findAll] will have correct data though
        }
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

interestingly, when I use following code, it works. seems the importing is done in background thread as well!

I really don't know in which context the importing is done, but the UI blocking issue is gone.

```
__block NSMutableArray *cars;
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
    for (NSDictionary *carObject in carObjects) {
        Notification *car = [Notification MR_importFromObject:carObject]; // not pass in localContext
        [cars addObject:car];
    }
} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        for (Car *car in cars) {
            // data may have invalid data or be nil
            // [Car findAll] will have correct data though
        }
    }
}];
```